# How to eliminate 3.3V regulator output spiking

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator, power-filtering

Using a this DC-DC converter
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/traco-power/TSR-1-2433E/12171286

Input is coming from this DC power supply
[https://www.amazon.com/TalentCell-PB240B1-Rechargeable-Batteries-Smartphone/dp/B07SWBS55F/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=21-29v+power+supply+talentcell&qid=1670265465&sr=8-8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SWBS55F)

The output of the power supply is fed directly to the input of the dc-dc converter with no filtering. The output of the dc-dc converter is powering an STM32F405, the STM has input filtering on its inputs.

The problem
I fried a few STM's and it seemed to be when unplugging or plugging in the barrel jack that supplies the dc-dc converter. I scoped the 3.3V bus and found that occasionally when you sloppily plug in the barrel jack the voltage ripples to upwards of 8V for a short period of time before settling. I'm in desperate need to understand what kind of filtering I need in this application to prevent my 3.3V bus from exceeding a maximum of 4.0V at any given time. Thank you in advance I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and usually reliable fix is to put a zener diode directly across the output of your TSR 1E Series 3.3 volt DC-to-DC converter. Your power source is ultimately a battery inside the [TalentCell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SWBS55F) so, there is no problem with common-mode glitches with respect to earth/ground. However, it is an Amazon sourced product with no data sheet so, bear this in mind.

The zener diode should be chosen so that it does not draw too much power when normally operating (maybe a few mA) but also, does not allow a peak voltage glitch greater than the maximum voltage allowed by the STM32F405. That information will be in it's data sheet. Waving my hands a bit, I suspect you may be able to use a 3 watt 3.3 volt zener diode.

Comment: Thanks, directly across the output do you mean in series or from output to ground?

Comment: From the output to 0 volts / ground. I would also consider putting a 100 uF capacitor across input to ground as well. @ErricDiFilippo

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to filter the input 21-29V prior to entering the input of the dc-dc converter? Can that be done with a zener as well?

Comment: No you can't really do that with a Zener but, if the original Zener idea is still troublesome I'd be wanting to put 100 uF capacitor on that input as well as the earlier one I mentioned @ErricDiFilippo

Comment: Curious to why you can’t or shouldn’t do that?

Answer (score 3):

The spec of Traco’s DC-DC converter says it provides 1000 mA continuous, with current limited to 350% meaning **current transients up to 3.5 A**. This is one of my concerns.  Another one is the the amplitude of voltage transient, said to could go as high as 8 V.
Depending how long it lasts (not mentioned), this could be another point of concern: if the over-voltage is more than just a “noise” spike, and behaves as a longer “rectangular” pulse, the 8V pulse could sustain a current up to 3.5 A.

The [Zener clamping proposed by Andy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/645171/248404) is at first the simplest way, no doubt, but I have concerns if it would be enough to really clamp a higher current spike, as datasheet of a [3.3V 3W Zener (1N5913B)](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1N5913B_D-1801544.pdf) shows its equivalent resistance of about 10 Ohms:

[image]

Depending how long this 8V transient happens, to avoid voltage spiking above 4V (120% of 3.3V), the shunting resistance should be 0.2 Ohm or lower.
It means that, **just a zener *might not* be enough**.

Another point, already mentioned by Andy is that the normal operation may have voltage variations (see above picture) that could result in higher shunt consumption, inefficient at best, or at worst destructive for the Zener.

If you still prefer to use a Zener, my suggestion would be to check & test Zeners that could be operating at their upper limit (as 3.45V) and see if this is enough to avoid over-voltage spikes.

My suggestion would be to do an Adjustable voltage shunt regulator using the adjustable and sharp knee of a [TL-431 Datasheet, Figure 10-7](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1670208411689) - see it as a **“High-Powered, Super-Precise Zener”**, that surely will have a much lower equivalent shunting resistance than a traditional Zener.
I believe your STM-based application is sensitive and expensive enough to justify such increased shunt protection.

[image]

Comment: I could get you a screen capture of what i'm experiencing, off the top of my head it was lasting at least 500uS

Comment: If you see the Zener spec, you can see it withstands surge rated as 98W for 1ms. So the problem is not related to Zener integrity, but its capability to shunt 8V towards ~4V. Probably a screen capture or ‘photo’ may motivate further discussions or additional answers.

Comment: @EJE, How did you determine the 0.2 Ohms value ? Thanks

Comment: @Vincent : Assuming V_max=4V, V_nom=3.3V, and i_lim=3.5A: shunting resistance assumed to be capable to drain maximum rated transient current (conservatively, but no the data available). R = (V_max - V_nom) / i_lim = (0.7) / 3.5 = 0.2 Ohm.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting this question as it has helped us confirm something that was happening to a product of ours. This post is really for anyone else that arrives here with a similar issue.

Rather than an STM32, we we're experiencing dead W5500 ethernet ICs. For all intents and purposes the chip would communicate over SPI, but was dead on the PHY side and no Ethernet link could be established.

We scoped the 3.3 V supply coming from the TSR and indeed can confirm similar results as you.

From our investigation, the spikes occur when the DC is very quickly (few ms) disconnected and reconnected. We saw spikes up to 7 V and for around 500 μs.

As per Andy Aka's suggestion, a 100 μF was tried and there was insignificant difference, however, we have since added a 470 μF, 6.3 V electrolytic across the 3.3 V and GND output and have reduced said spikes to a maximum of 4.3 V and the time period to 100 μs (from what I remember). This seems to be adequate to protect the W5500 IC.

Image below is where we are stroking a +24 V feed on the input pin to cause as much noise/power interruption as possible; it seemed to be an easy way to trigger the spikes. This was with the caps in place; I forgot to screenshot the original failure pattern.

[image]

Over the last 72 hr period we have rigged up a relay power cycling 4 boards (500 ms drop outs), 2 with the fix and 2 without. As we had hoped, the 2 non-capped boards have malfunctioned and the 2 with caps continue to operate within spec. It may not be the perfect solution, but it is adequate at the moment; we will continue to power cycle the working boards to see if we get further failures.

Comment: Interesting post, Aaron. On that screen shown, the DC is ~3.3V and the positive spikes close to +1V. I understand that adding a 470uF electrolytic improved a lot, from 7V x 500us. The remaining duration seems quite shorter now (100us), just an electrolytic capacitor seem to work for the longer duration pulses. 
My question here: Along your investigations, have you tried a ceramic or polyester cap too, with the 470uF in parallel?

Comment: Aaron, I also discovered that just switching the input supply power switch from ON-OFF-ON was causing the issue, from memory, it seemed that when the TSR was just about to drop out and then switched back on, things got messy. I'm glad you were able to find a bandaid!

Comment: EJE - No, I was under time pressure to get a fix in place as we had failing hardware on site. I have a new board revision coming, when this arrives, I may try some more cap options.

Erric, thanks for the observation, I think we have experienced the same issue, but hopefully the cap resolves it more or less. It's a shame the problem only manifests in down stream broken ICs.

Answer (score 0):

A supervisory load switch could help. This is different than a regular supervisor that just holds things in reset. It basically keeps the power disconnected from everything unless it is within acceptable bounds. It's a common enough application that it exists as an IC.